# Launchpad X Causes Power Surge on USB Ports

Tags: electronics, drum-hardware, windows

Essentially what the title says. I recently picked up a lightly-used Launchpad X. Out of the box, it was working fine. It lit up, was receiving power, and was recognized by my computer. That was, however, until I ran a firmware update using Novation Components to bring it up to the latest version. For whatever reason, this firmware update broke the Launchpad X, and now every time I connect it to my PC, it says it is causing a power surge on my USB port. I've tried different USB cables, different ports on the PC, changed my PC's power settings per Novation's online documentation and even tried plugging it in on a different PC just to ensure it wasn't a hardware issue on my computer. Each time, the result was the same: a flood of Windows errors saying an unknown USB device is trying to draw more power than the PC can provide. Is there any possible fix for this, or should I chalk it up to a loss?

I tried googling the issue before making this post, and couldn't find any other resources online. I also tried addressing this with the manufacturer — no response, no live chat on their site in the US, as well as no US phone number. Figured I would have more luck asking the community and see if anyone has some first-hand experience with similar issues

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's a basic customer support question, better addressed to the manufacturer/developer.

Comment: I tried addressing the manufacturer, no response, no live chat on their site in the US, as well as no US phone number. Figured I would have more luck asking the community and see if anyone has some first-hand experience with similar issues.

Comment: Have you tried a powered USB hub?

Comment: I haven't, no. I'm going to get one if that is the only solution, though. I was under the impression that the Launchpad X was natively bus-powered, so I wanted to exhaust all my other options first before shelling out cash for a new piece of equipment.

Comment: Sounds like you briked it which can happen when you update firmwares of any device (hence the usual "do not power off!"). But if you did everything correctly then you would have a better chancewith the manufacturer ...